# How do I track all directories in a git-lfs repository without specifying each directory in .gitattributes?

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have a git LFS repository that is used for storing data files used by my project.  Most of these files are tens of megabytes in size, but a few are text files, mostly `*.csv` and `*.json`.  I want to have the CSV and JSON files tracked in git as text, with the data files (`*.tif`) tracked in LFS.  These files are all distributed across directories in the repository.

Let's say that my repository has this structure (in the real world, files in my repository have about 25 different file extensions):

```
folder1/
folder1/subdir1/foo.tif
folder1/folder1.csv
folder1/folder1.json
folder2/
folder2/folder2.json
folder2/bar.tif
```

This `.gitattributes` configuration does what I want it to:

```
folder1/** filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
folder2/** filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
**/*.json filter= diff= merge= text
**/*.csv filter= diff= merge= text
```

But I would prefer to have a single line be able to capture all of the files in all of the directories, so that if I add more directories with data files, I don't have to add another line in `.gitattributes`.  Is this possible?

This is what I'd like to have:

```
**/** filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
**/*.json filter= diff= merge= text
**/*.csv filter= diff= merge= text
```

But this does not work as expected.

Comment: Is there a reason `*.tif` wouldn't work?

Comment: In my real-world repository I have a whole bunch of extensions.  These are spatial files, so `*.gpkg`, `*.shp` and whole lot more.

Comment: otomh : try `**/*` (one single `*` at the end) to match anything. or `**` alone